# What is the Shape of the Quadrupole Magnets Used for Beam Focusing?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, accelerator-physics

This question comes from Particle Detectors by Grupen. Quadrupoles are used in accelerators for beam focusing. To achieve focusing effect, the angle at which the quadrupoles bend the particle beam must be proportional to the beam excursion in x:

$\theta=\frac{eB_y}{p}l \propto x$

so $B_y l \propto x$

where $l$ is the length of the bending magnet.

By symmetry, $B_x l\propto y$. Which magnetic potential fulfills these conditions, and what is the shape of the surface of the quadrupole magnet?

I solved the first part and got the magnetic potential:
$A=\frac{k z}{l}x\hat{x}+\frac{kz}{l}y\hat{y}$.
But I have no idea how to get the second part.

Comment: I believe they're just circular rings and the magnetization of the domains alternates. For an example of even more complicated manipulation of domains, see: magnetic hard drives, and the sort of magnets produced by Polymagnet and covered in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IANBoybVApQ .

Comment: Many of the quadrupole's used in accelerators are not permanent magnets at all, but are fully electromagnetic. This is needed in order to control the beam tune. You should also watch out for your "by symmetry" argument here, because while the proportionality is true one axis has the opposite sign relative the other (one axis converging the other diverging). They must be used in groups to control  the tendency of the beam to spread. BTW-Fermilab's logo is a stylized septupole (unified dipole and quadrupole).

Comment: The "by symmetry" argument was part of the problem from the book. I'm sorry for not being clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem with help from "An Introduction to the Physics of High Energy Acceleration" by Edwards Syphers. Apparently, the magnetic potential in the problem is **not the magnetic vector potential**. It actually means the **magnetic scalar potential**.

If we express the magnetic field as

$\vec{B}=\nabla \phi_M$

and solve for $\phi_M$, the contour lines of constant $\phi_M$ is the equipotential lines for the magnetic field. (We are allowed to express $\vec{B}$ this way, because we are looking at the "empty" space surrounded by the quadrupole, which is a current-free region. From Maxwell's equation, $\nabla\times\vec{B}=0$  since $\vec{J}=0$) Just like how the equipotential lines for electric field help us know the geometry of the charge distribution, these equipotential lines for the magnetic field tell us the shape of the magnets.